# How can I rollback Jenkins config when using the SCM sync configuration plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the Jenkins SCM sync configuration plugin set up and working with a git repo, but there's no obvious way to roll back to an earlier version of the settings. How do I do this? I thought of rolling back the commits in the repo (or moving master to a different commit), but how do I tell Jenkins to reload from git?

Answer (score 2):

Found it - the reload link is in the section in the config where you specify the git repo.

It doesn't work for me because of a bug where it leaves out a part of the URL. If you are at http://myserver.org/jenkins/ then it will leave out the 'jenkins' bit and you get a 404. Manually adding it back in makes the url work.